# Custom Ajax add to cart and changing product price in WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I need help please. I have the following ajax request in the front

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#pagoboton').click(function() {
        var product_id = 14589; // Reemplaza con el ID del producto que deseas cotizar
        var product_price = 200; // Reemplaza con el precio modificado que desees - new price
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo home_url('wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
    
        $.post( ajaxurl, {   
            action: 'cotizar_producto',
            product_id: product_id,
            product_price: product_price
        }, function(response){
            window.location.href = response.redirect_url;
        });                          
    });
});
```

And in the functions.php file i have

```
 add_action('wp_ajax_cotizar_producto', 'cotizar_producto');
 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_cotizar_producto', 'cotizar_producto');

 function cotizar_producto() {

// Obtener los datos del formulario
$product_id = $_REQUEST['product_id'];
$product_price = floatval($_REQUEST['product_price']); // Convertir el precio a número decimal
WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, 1, $variation_id = 0, array(), array('total' => $product_price));

add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', function ($cart) use ($product_id, $product_price) {
    //if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) return;

    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        // Verificar si es el producto que deseas modificar
        if ($cart_item['product_id'] == $product_id) {
            // Define el nuevo precio que deseas asignar
            $nuevo_precio = $product_price;

            // Establece el nuevo precio para el producto
            $cart_item['data']->set_price($nuevo_precio);

            // Actualiza el carrito
            $cart->cart_contents[$cart_item_key] = $cart_item;
        }
    }
});

wp_die();

//here i need the code to redirect to the payment page

}
```

I tested, but not worked, I was hoping that by clicking on the button with id = #pagoboton a specific product could be added to the cart, changing its price and redirecting it to the payment page

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in your code... Try the following instead:

```php
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_add_to_cart_js');
function custom_add_to_cart_js() {
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#pagoboton').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            const product_id = 14589, 
                  price = 200; 
    
            $.ajax({
                url: <?php echo json_encode(admin_url('admin-ajax.php')) ?>,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    action: 'custom_add_to_cart',
                    product_id: product_id,
                    price: price
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    window.location.href = response;
                },
            });                        
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action('wp_ajax_custom_add_to_cart', 'custom_add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_add_to_cart', 'custom_add_to_cart');
function custom_add_to_cart() {
    if ( isset($_REQUEST['product_id']) && isset($_REQUEST['price']) ) {
        $product_id    = intval($_REQUEST['product_id']);
        $price         = floatval($_REQUEST['price']); 
        $cart_item_key = WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, 1, 0, [], ['custom_price' => $price] );
        if ( $cart_item_key ) {
            wp_send_json( wc_get_checkout_url() );
        }
    }
    wp_die();
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'change_product_price' );
function change_product_price($cart) {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) return;

    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item) {
        if ( isset($cart_item['custom_price'])) {
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( floatval($cart_item['custom_price']) );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.